# Ability to flag comments

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am not able to flag any comments on Channels. The flag pop up doesn't appear. I would like to flag the too chatty comments in Channels:

[image]

Would there be an option to flag the comments on channels?

Comment: Is that your screen shot or Sam's. Seems weird there's an edit and delete next to Sam's comment...?

Comment: @JonClements I'm a mod there as well. So I get the ability to delete comments.

Comment: Ahhh... yes... that thing with the no diamond showing... Just delete the comments and then those guys - they're both just trouble makers anyway :p

Comment: if you can delete the comments, why flagging them?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: we can flag comments on the main site. If I wanted to document why I deleted a comment, I'd use a custom flag so the reason is recorded.